# Grails - if value is negative, show value as 0

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

[image: Table of Asset]

This is the formula code in `asset.groovy`

```
static mapping = {
    yearNow formula: 'YEAR(purchase_date)'
    yearlyValue formula: 'PURCHASE_AMOUNT / LIFE_EXPECTANCY'
    value formula: 'PURCHASE_AMOUNT / LIFE_EXPECTANCY * (LIFE_EXPECTANCY - (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(purchase_date)))'
}
```

I need to declare Value as 0 if the value resulting from value formula is -ve.
How do I do this, is it in controller or domain?

I tried this in Controller

```
@Transactional
def value() {
    Asset asset = Asset.get(params.value)
    if (params.value <= 0) {
        params.value = 0
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help, the answer is

```
 value formula: 'GREATEST(PURCHASE_AMOUNT / LIFE_EXPECTANCY * (LIFE_EXPECTANCY - (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(purchase_date))), 0)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well! right now I'm not able to try the suggestion I'm giving to you but it's well said in grails docs that formula uses persistence model and not the object model and hence it allows adding hql queries as well.

So, you could try using an hql query `CASE` statement.

[This blog](http://wordpress.transentia.com.au/wordpress/2012/11/02/derived-properties-in-grails/) well shows such example of using hql.

Below is something that should work in your case:

```
static mapping = {
    yearNow formula: 'YEAR(purchase_date)'
    yearlyValue formula: 'PURCHASE_AMOUNT / LIFE_EXPECTANCY'
    value formula: 'CASE WHEN PURCHASE_AMOUNT / LIFE_EXPECTANCY * (LIFE_EXPECTANCY - (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(purchase_date))) <0 THEN PURCHASE_AMOUNT / LIFE_EXPECTANCY * (LIFE_EXPECTANCY - (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(purchase_date))) ELSE 0'
```

Also, another solution *if you don't want to use finders or criteria queries over your formula* is to create a custom getter method for a transient property and there get the expected value something like below:

```
public double getValue(){
    double value = 0.0d //calculate value here
    return  (value <0 ? 0 : value)
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for the late reply, unfortunately they didn't work for me. The first block quote was very near what I needed though.

Answer (score 1):

Just override the getter method for `value` inside domain to check for -ve value.

```
public double getValue(){
    value < 0 ? 0 : value
}
```